# Dropdown Menu Pure CSS issue

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a dropdown, but I can't get it to go vertical and blocks. Here is the HTML and CSS. All this does is create a list of links with bullets.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html {
background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
#container {
min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#06F;
    padding:0px;
}
#body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:60px;    /* Height of the 
     */
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:68%;
    text-align:center;          /* Height of the footer */
    }
/* other non-essential CSS */
#header p,
#header h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
}
#footer p {
    margin:-10px;
    padding:0px;
}
#wrapper {
width : 1025px;
margin : 0 auto;
}
#logo h3 {
float : right;
margin-right : 100px;
font-weight : bold;
color : #00adef;
height : 60px;
line-height : 60px;
}
#logo img {
outline : none;
border : none;
width: 500px;
padding-left: 275px;
}
#global-nav {
width: 121px;
float: left;
background: #e8eef4;
}
.global-subnav {
width: 121px;
background: #09C;
}

#global-nav a {
color: #034af3;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;   
text-indent: 10px;               
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;
}

#global-nav ul{
background: yellow;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#global-subnav ul{
background: orangered;
position: relative;
top: -10px;
left: 40px;
}

#global-nav li{
list-style: none;   
border-bottom: #5C87B2 solid;
border-width: 3px;
}

#global-nav ul ul li{
display:none;
}

#global-nav li:hover {
background: #fff;
}

#global-nav li:hover ul li{
display:block;
}
#rightnav {
float: left;
width: 220px;
 background: url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat-y;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px
}
#innercontent {
margin-top : 50px;
}
#minorcontent {
padding : 5px;
width : 200px;
border : #00adef solid 2px;
margin-top : 20px;
float : right;
margin-right : 10px;
text-align : center;
}
#majorcontent {
width : auto;
font-size : 0.95em;
background-color: #FFF;
}
#majorcontent h4 {
height : 25px;
line-height : 25px;
padding-left : 10px;
background-color : #06F;
color: #FFBF00;
} 
#majorcontent p {
float : right;
width : 910px;
margin : -300px;
padding : 0;
white-space : pre;
}
#majorcontent img {
border : #ccc solid 4px;
}
.clear {
clear : both;
}
#NewFooter {
padding-top:0px;
text-align:right;
list-style:none;
}
#NewFooterInner {
width:auto;
margin:0 auto;
padding:20px 0 35px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#NewFooterInner .sectionFooter {
float:left;
width:600px;
padding-right:30px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-bottom:40px;
}
#NewFooterInner h2 {
font-size:20px;
border-bottom:1px solid #292929;
padding:7px 0 12px;
margin-bottom:2px;
color:#FFBF00;
}
#NewFooterInner .sectionFooter ul li {
padding:7px 0;
border-bottom:1px solid #292929;
color:#986123;
font-size:10px;
font-style:italic;
}
#NewFooterInner .sectionFooter ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#515151;
font-size:13px;
font-style:normal;
}
#NewFooterInner #copyright {
clear:both;
padding-top:25px;
margin-top:15px;
position:relative;
}
#address {
text-align : center;
color : #000;
margin : 0 auto;
margin-top : 50px;
background-color : #fff;
padding : 20px;
height : 700px;
}
#about {
margin-top : 50px;
padding : 20px;
background-color : #fff;
}
#about h4 {
width : 500px;
border-bottom : 2px solid #09f;
}
#projvol {
background-color : #fff;
margin-top : 50px;
height : auto;
padding : 20px;
}
#projvol h4 {
width : 500px;
border-bottom : 2px solid #09f;
}
#projvol img {
margin-left: 25px;
padding : 0px 20px 20px;
}
#images {
margin-top : 10px;
margin-bottom : 100px;
}
#images h5 {
margin-left : 50px;
}
#images img {
border : #ccc solid 5px;
float : left;
margin-left : 50px;
margin-top : 30px;
}
#social {
position:absolute;
right:160px;
top:100px;
}

#social ul li {
float:left;
padding:0 5px;
width:50px;
 list-style: none outside none;
}

#social ul li a {
display:block;
height:47px;
width:47px;
}

#social ul li a img {
border:none;
margin-top:12px;
margin-left:8px;
}
```

End of CSS

Start of HTML code

```
<body onload="info()">
<div id="container">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" height="80" width="400" /></div>
<div id="header">
<div id="global-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#One">One</a>
<div class="global-subnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#A">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#B">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#C">C</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li><a href="#Two">Two</a>
<div class="global-subnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div> </div>
```

I erased some non-essential stuff so disregard the quotes.

Comment: The code for the menu was copied from a question I found on here, all code gets the same list of link results not the dropdown.

Comment: if you can, link to a jsFIddle example. And no one needs to see your <head> or your doctype or your google analytics

Comment: @charset"utf-8"; in css file. dreamweaver detected! As a sidenote I can not see a problem on the fiddle, and the image looks like there is no css applied at all.

Comment: that was my bad, it wasn't updated I got the menu to appear, now I just need the menus side by side instead of on top of each other lol
http://jsfiddle.net/SZqvh/1/

Comment: For that you can [check this out](http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-a-pure-css-horizontal-navigation-with-drop-downs). [Demo here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css_navigation/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing "}" after your html css tag, so it any css after is not being used. Add that and your code will work.

Comment: that was taken off while I was fixing the code to post on here, so disregard that lol.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to post something on imgr instead of coding something to a site. You may have to do inline css to make it work or it may not work at all depending on imgr's web and what it allows you to put into the posts.